# can't access property "innerHTML", document.getElementById('id' +num) even though js is declared at the end of <body>

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to pick a random value for each row of the array in js, however when i run the code i get Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "innerHTML", document.getElementById(...) is null even though the script is at the bottom of

```
 <p id="crit1"></p>
            <p id="crit2"></p>
            <p id="crit3"></p>
            <p id="crit4"></p>
            <p id="crit5"></p>

        <script>
        

            var criteria = [
              ['opt1', 'opt2'], 
              ['opt3', 'opt4'],
              ['opt5', 'opt6'], 
              ['opt7', 'opt8'], 
              ['opt9', 'opt10']
            ];

            for (var step = 0; step <5; step++){
                var rand = Math.round(Math.random()); //genrates either 0 or 1
                if (rand == 1) {
                    document.getElementById('crit'+ step).innerHTML = criteria[step][1];
                    var answ = answ +1;
                } else {
                    document.getElementById('crit'+ step).innerHTML = criteria[step][0];
                }
            }
```

Comment: Always try debugging before asking. A simple `console.log('crit'+ step)` at the beginning of your loop would have revealed your error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's failing because your `step` counter starts at 0 but you have no element with ID `crit0`.

If you add a `crit0` element or start your counter at 1, the error goes away.

It can also be helpful to also include a null check for `document.getElementByID()` to avoid throwing errors when it can't find the element:

```
const critElement = document.getElementById('crit' + step);
if (critElement) {
    critElement.innerHTML = criteria[step][0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The step is start from 0. So, the first iteration will find the element with `id=crit0`. There is no id with that name. You can change the start iteration from 1 instead.